# Executing all cases one after another inside a for loop in octave

Tags: octave

Until now, I change `req` manually. The code works, including saving the result into a file.
But now I want to run the code for all possible values of req.

Without saving it into a file, the code works but obviously it overwrite the result.
That is why I put that line of code that saving the result by giving it a different name depending of the values of `req`. But this gives me error.

error:

> ```
> error: sprintf: wrong type argument 'cell'
> error: called from
>     testforloop at line 26 column 1
> ```

my code:

```
clear all;
clc;

for req = {"del_1", "del_2", "del_3"}

request = req;

  if (strcmp(request, "del_1"))
  tarr = 11; 
  # and a bunch of other variables
  elseif (strcmp(request, "del_2"))
  tarr = 22; 
  # and a bunch of other variables
  elseif (strcmp(request, "del_3"))
  tarr = 33; 
  # and a bunch of other variables
  else
  # do nothing
  endif


#long calculation producing many variable including aa, bb, cc.
aa = 2 * tarr;
bb = 3 * tarr;
cc = 4 * tarr;

#collecting variables of interest: aa, bb, cc and save it to a file.
result_matrix = [aa bb cc];
dlmwrite (sprintf('file_result_%s.csv', request), result_matrix);

endfor
```

if I use `["del_1" "del_2" "del_3"]`, the error is

```
error: 'tarr' undefined near line 20 column 10
error: called from
    testforloop at line 20 column 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the loop

```
for req = {"del_1", "del_2", "del_3"}
```

`req` gets as value each of the cells of the cell array, not the contents of the cells (weird design decision, IMO, but this is the way it works). Thus, `req={"del_1"}` in the first iteration. The string itself can then be obtained with `req{1}`. So all you need to change is:

```
request = req{1};
```

---

However, I would implement this differently, as so:

```
function myfunction(request, tarr)
  % long calculation producing many variable including aa, bb, cc.
  aa = 2 * tarr;
  bb = 3 * tarr;
  cc = 4 * tarr;

  % collecting variables of interest: aa, bb, cc and save it to a file.
  result_matrix = [aa bb cc];
  dlmwrite (sprintf('file_result_%s.csv', request), result_matrix);
end

myfunction("del_1", 11)
myfunction("del_2", 22)
myfunction("del_3", 33)
```

I think this obtains a clearer view of what you're actually doing, the code is less complicated.

---

Note that in Octave, `["del_1" "del_2" "del_3"]` evaluates to `"del_1del_2del_3"`. That is, you concatenate the strings. In MATLAB this is not the case, but Octave doesn't know the `string` type, and uses `"` in the same way as `'` to create `char` arrays.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
the thing is, `tarr` is not the only variable for each member of `req`.
sorry, I was not clear before. I edit my post above.

so, listing all variables as argument like your suggestion would be difficult.

Comment: @Codelearner777: Fair enough. I hope the first bit of the answer sill solves your problem, though.

Comment: just got back into this. it works. `request = req{1};` and `request = req;` work.
but it seems like the content of request is not considered as a string.
I checked `isstring(req(1))`, `isstring(req)`, `isstring(request(1))`, `isstring(request)`,  all give `0`.

Comment: it turns out either I missread your code or misstyped my code. `request = req{1};` and `request = req{};` work for the loop and for naming the saved file. thanks